# RandomForest multiclass-multioutput Scores?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

When using RandomForest I get the following error :

```
  self.scores = metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, self.y_pred)

   ValueError: multiclass-multioutput is not supported
```

I think it is because I use multiple-integer labels, instead of one-hot labels.
I have to use integer-labels.

Is there a way to calculate scores in my scenario ?

Answer (score 0):

This seems the correct solution so far :

```
def scores(original, predicted):
  row_matches = np.sum(np.all(original == predicted, axis=1))
  row_total = float(original.shape[0])

  matches = np.sum(original == predicted)
  total = (row_total * original.shape[1])

  mse = ((original - predicted)**2).mean(axis=1).mean()


  return { 'acc_row' : row_matches/row_total, 'acc_items' : matches/total, 'mse': mse }
```